# how to add logo on the top of the page header and footer - 1st page in pdf?

Tags: header-footer

I would like to amend the following code so as to add in the header a logo and in the footer some text. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} % for A4 size paper
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

\tikzset{normal lines/.style={gray, very thin}} 
\tikzset{margin lines/.style={gray, thick}} 
\tikzset{mm lines/.style={gray, ultra thin}} 
\tikzset{strong lines/.style={black, very thin}} 
\tikzset{master lines/.style={black, very thick}} 
\tikzset{dashed master lines/.style={loosely dashed, black, very thick}} 

\node at ([xshift=1cm, yshift=8.5mm] current page.south west){
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

    \draw[style=mm lines,step=1mm] (0,0) grid +(19cm,28cm); 
    \draw[style=strong lines,step=1cm] (0,0) grid +(19cm,28cm); 

  \end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `tikz` already, here's an easy solution that uses the `current page` node (which you already are using).  I also simplified your code a little bit.  I hope that's what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} % for A4 size paper
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  normal lines/.style={gray, very thin}, 
  margin lines/.style={gray, thick}, 
  mm lines/.style={gray, ultra thin}, 
  strong lines/.style={black, very thin}, 
  master lines/.style={black, very thick}, 
  dashed master lines/.style={loosely dashed, black, very thick}
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikz [remember picture, overlay]
  \node at (current page.center) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[style=mm lines,step=1mm] (0,0) grid +(19cm,28cm); 
      \draw[style=strong lines,step=1cm] (0,0) grid +(19cm,28cm); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };

\tikz [remember picture, overlay]
  \node [anchor=north] at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[height=0.6cm]{example-image-a}};
\tikz [remember picture, overlay]
  \node [anchor=south] at (current page.south) {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent viverra turpis ac semper auctor.};

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

#### Addendum

You refer in your title to the first page of the PDF.  I'm guessing that you want this graph-paper to be printer on every page, but only the first page features the logo and text?  You can easily create many more pages featuring the grid with:

```
  \foreach \i in {1, 2, ..., 49} {
    \clearpage
    \tikz [remember picture, overlay]
      \node at (current page.center) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw[style=mm lines,step=1mm] (0,0) grid +(19cm,28cm); 
          \draw[style=strong lines,step=1cm] (0,0) grid +(19cm,28cm); 
        \end{tikzpicture}
      };
  }
```

which can be added just before `\end{document}` in the above example. This will result in 50 pages of graph paper, with the first one only featuring the logo and text.