# how to add logo to the header of first page in the documents

Tags: header-footer

I would like to add a logo to the header of my titlepage. I am not using \maketitle to create my title page, whereas all suggestions in other posts actually use it.
Could someone help me out and provide a fix to this problem? I only want my logo to be in the header on the first page which is titlepage.

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\centerline{
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{logo.png}
}
    \vspace*{1cm}

    \Huge
    \textbf{title}


    \vspace{1.5cm}

by
    \textbf{name}\\
\vspace{1.5cm}
\Large
supervised by
\textbf{name}

    \vfill

    A report presented for the degree of...

    \vspace{0.8cm} 

    Department of... \\

    \vspace{1.5cm}

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: I don’t really understand what you want to do. Can you provide a picture of the result at this time and make a sketch of what you want to do? Also, you don’t need `\centerline` inside the `center` environment.

Comment: Basically my logo is in the space of the page where all of the text goes. Header is not used, so in fact the logo is below the header. I would like to place the logo inside the header.

Comment: Then you should edit your question. It’s doable with TikZ as you can access several nodes to put your picture in the right place. I am not fluent enough with TikZ to write the answer but you could find the solution by searching for it on TeX.SX.

Comment: I will try look into it. However, maybe someone will suggest a solution that uses for example fancyhdr. It seems to be used a lot when dealing with headers and footers

Comment: I think that creating a whole new header & footer style for only one page is a little bit bloating and less semantically correct. If you already use TikZ in your document, it’s the best solution IMHO.

Comment: I suggest the `titling` package, which defines  hooks to easily customize the title page. No TikZ required.

Comment: [Some hints for TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292858/how-to-add-logo-on-the-top-of-the-page-header-and-footer-1st-page-in-pdf)

Comment: @Zoxume -- Using TikZ for a single header is much more 'bloated' than definint a page style (though a page style is not required here): TikZ is an absolutely massive package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic way to do it. (It assumes the logo should take up the whole physical page.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, mwe,graphicx,eso-pic}
% lipsum provides:   \lipsum
% mwe provides:      example-image
% graphicx provides: \includegraphics
% eso-pic provides:  \AddTo..., \AtStockUpperLeft

\newlength\headpicwd
\newlength\headpicht
\setlength{\headpicwd}{\pdfpagewidth}% image width of physical page?
\setlength{\headpicht}{3cm}
\newcommand\printpic{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \AtStockUpperLeft{%
      \raisebox{-\headpicht}{%
        % centred with respect to physical page ..?
        % \hspace*{\dimexpr 0.5\pdfpagewidth - 0.5\headpicwd\relax}%
        \includegraphics[width=\headpicwd, height=\headpicht]{example-image}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
% print logo
\printpic

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

If you want to change that, set `\headpicwd` to the appropriate width and uncomment the `\hspace` line. If you want it centred with respect to the text block some further (minor) changes would be required if you have different margin sizes.

Comment: Jon it did the trick without changing anything (excluding filename). Accepted as an answer.

Comment: @aki2014 -- Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution with the  `titling` package and a simple `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{garamondx}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titling}%
\title{Title}
\author{by\quad Name}
\date{}

\pretitle{\begin{center} \Huge\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}\vskip1.5cm}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries}
\postauthor{\vskip1.5cm\par\Large supervised by supername\end{center}\vfill}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{%
\noindent\centering\raisebox{95pt}[0pt][0cm]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{dodo.jpeg}}}%
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%
\noindent\raggedright A report presented for the degree of...
\vspace{0.8cm}\\
Department of...
\vspace{1.5cm}}%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]